# open type dialog is empty - RSA (Rational Software Architetc) for WebSphere 7.5.0 on Linux (Ubuntu 9.04)

Tags: eclipse, rational-rsa, ibm-rational

I have a fresh install of RSA 7.5.3 in Linux (Ubuntu 9.04).
I've create a new workspace with one Java project.
When I open the "open type" dialog I get an empty box - see attached [screenshot](http://img215.yfrog.com/i/screenshot26.png/).
You can notice that there is no package specified at the bottom of the dialog.
when I try to look for a class I get the following exception:

```
Error occurred during status handling
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: -1
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer$VirtualManager.resolveElement
(Unknown Source)!
```

-- Yonatan

Comment: [solved] it is eclipse 3.4 probem with specific  GTK version 
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=240033

Comment: Good catch! I have updated my answer to reflect and detail the content of bug 24033.

Answer (score 0):

Well, someone has actually the exact same issue [on developerworks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14292064&tstart=0)!
Oh wait... that would be you ;)

May be RSA is preventing the Java initialization job to even start, which would be a problem as commented in [bug 192112](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=192112).

If not, a new bug on bugs.eclipse.org would be in order.

---

Actually, as the OP [Yonatan Maman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20065/yonatan-maman) mentions in the comments the actual source of the problem: [bug 240033](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=240033).

> After upgrading from 3.3 to 3.4, both the Open Type and Open Type Hierarchy
>   dialogs no long work.
>
> So latest Ubuntu fails, but RHEL 5 is ok.

Linked to a GNOME gail issue ([bug 575873](http://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=575873)) affecting only on new version of GTK+GAIL, as in Fedora 9 and 10, Ubuntu 8.04 and 8.10, etc.

Fixed in eclipse3.5: the [final fix](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=130762) mentions:

```
/*
 *  Bug in GTK. With GTK 2.12, when assistive technologies is on, the time
 * it takes to add or remove several rows to the model is very long. This
 * happens because the accessible object asks each row for its data, including
 * the rows that are not visible. The the fix is to block the accessible object
 * from receiving row_added and row_removed signals and, at the end, send only
 * a notify signal with the "model" detail.
 */
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As speculated in the bug tracker it's a GTK issue.

Putting following in your eclipse.ini, which is located in your eclipse installation directory, should solve/workaround the issue:

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```

This should be put under the -startup parameter. E.g.:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```